# Closure with a Lazy Adder Function

Tags: javascript, arguments, closures, parameter-passing

I'm stuck on a problem that uses a closure function to add the arguments of subsequent functions into a sum function:

> Write a function named: lazyAdder(firstNum). The lazyAdder function
> will accept a number and return a function. When the function returned
> by lazyAdder is invoked it will again accept a number, (secondNum),
> and then return a function. When the last mentioned function is
> invoked with a number, (thirdNum), it will FINALLY return a number.
> See below for examples!
>
> Example 1:
>
> ```
> let firstAdd = lazyAdder(1);
> let secondAdd = firstAdd(2);
> let sum = secondAdd(3);
> console.log(sum); // prints 6
> ```
>
> Example 2:
>
> ```
> let func1 = lazyAdder(10);
> let func2 = func1(20);
> let total = func2(3);
> console.log(total); // prints 33
> ```

I tried:

```
const lazyAdder = f => g => h => x => f(g(h))(h(x));
```

Thinking it takes in two function inputs (firstNum + secondNum = sum1), then adds a third (thirdNum + sum1 = sum2).
This did invoke the function twice; however, it did not return the sum - it returned an anonymous function.

Comment: "*it takes in two function inputs*" - no it shouldn't. The description of all the functions in the requirements says "*will accept a number*".

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correctly, what you are tasked to do is to perform a sum in a sequence of evaluations (i.e. pass arguments at different times). In a non-lazy approach, you would simply make a function `sum` which takes 3 parameters `x`, `y` and `z` and sum this: `sum(1, 2, 3) = 7`. Now to do this the "lazy" way, you have to perform an operation on this function called [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). I suggest reading up on this, as this is essentially what is asked.

Currying such a function can be done quite easily in JavaScript. As you showed, you can just chain the arguments in a function declaration:

```
const func = arg1 => arg2 => arg3 => ... // Some logic performed here
```

Now you can call this function 3 times until it returns something other than a closure; a value.
How do you make sure that when you `func(1)(2)(3)` it returns the sum, which is 6?

Since I suspect this is a homework assignment, I do not want to give you the plain answer. Therefore, it is up to you to define what logic should be put inside the function to sum these values. What is important is that the definition I gave, is already a definition of [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation).